# How do you use Greasemonkey scripts in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, greasemonkey

How do you use Greasemonkey scripts in Chrome and/or Chromuim?

A web search reveals only conflicting, outdated information. Some sources state that Chrome currently has support, others say that only beta builds of Chromium do. Some say that scripts go in "c:\scripts", and others mention a folder in "Application Data".

If anyone has gotten user scripts working, what's the truth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to http://build.chromium.org/buildbot/snapshots/chromium-rel-xp and grab the latest build (higher folder number includes newer build).
2. Create C:\Scripts & copy your userscripts there. Notice that unlike Greasemonkey for Firefox, Chromium ignores the @include meta data - but otherwise most Greasemonkey functions are supported.
3. Run Chromium with the --enable-greasemonkey flag.
4. Enjoy a bit more customized web =)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these websites below.  They may be of assistance.  It does look possible.

- [techie-buzz](http://techie-buzz.com/google-chrome/how-to-install-greasemonkey-script-in-google-chrome.html)
- [mashable](http://mashable.com/2008/12/15/google-chrome-greasemonkey-scripts/)
- [gHacks](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/10/18/google-chrome-adds-greasemonkey-support/)

Answer (score 0):

you could try [chrome dev channel build](http://dev.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel), it's still in development (as the name of channel says) where you run user-scripts inside google chrome. Greasemonkey API calls will probably not work, but it will pure javascript and Chrome API calls.

[Extensions HowTo](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/howto)